# PDF breaks when downloaded from a website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

This is my code:

```
<a style={{marginLeft: '10px', width: '100%'}} download
    href={'/assets/Polityka-prywatnosci.pdf'}>
    Przeczytałem(-am) i rozumiem politykę ochrony
    prywatnosci.
</a>
```

I am using Reacj.js.

So I need this file to be downloadable. To make things strange it works when I use `yarn start` and use the `localhost:3000` route, but as soon as I push it to the live server the pdfs get corrupted.

The pdfs in the `build` folder are valid and I can open them in a pdf viewer. So I think something is messing up when downloading the file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up using google drive to host the file. A cheat but it works

Answer (score 0):

Can be something related to privileges on the server related to the user for the application